# Invoking instance method as if it was static through reflection

Tags: java, .net

From simplified perspective, all methods in .Net are actually static. Instance methods invoked by implicitly passing reference to `this` to first method argument. So, it is possible to call instance method without actually supplying correct instance, making it to behave like static method. E.g. it is possible to call `string.Equals(string s)` as `null.Equals(null)` either by dynamic emitting `call` OpCode instead of `callvirt` or writing corresponding IL code by hand. As I recall, this situation maybe actually encountered if the code was jitted in runtime. And there would be no problem if `this` is not used within method body.

This thing provides demonstration that methods are actually static in .Net. I'd like to know if there are similar tricks in Java. I've looked through `Method.invoke()` - it is very thorough in checking that instance methods are not invoked without correct instances, and `NullPointerException` is guaranteed for null instance. Mostly because all methods in Java are virtual, and for virtual call correct type is required.

So, is there any trick way to call instance method as if it was static in Java (maybe due to some optimization, e.g. if only one method implementation exists in runtime, virtual call can be changed to non-virtual call)? Or is forbidden due to possible existence of real instance methods (every instance of type has its own method body for that method, not shared between them)?

Comment: Just one little question: Why?

Comment: @ Florian Schaetz To have Proof-of-concept. I'd like to know if java methods also are actually static in runtime, or it is implementation-specific, or it is possible in principle to introduce real instance methods.

Comment: That instance methods in .Net are invoked with the target instance as an implicit first parameter does not make them "static" in the usual sense of the term.  In fact, that's not too bad a definition of *non*-static.  Can you use different terms to describe what you're really trying to get at?

Comment: At least in .Net member of type is called static if it "belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object". By "all methods are static" i mean that even instance methods belongs to the type itself (and are stored in method table associated with type), and it is possible to use them without supplying actual instance. I'm trying to understand if the same is true for java, or it is possible to have method in java that belongs to instance (and stored in method table associated with specific object)

Comment: Actually I think there are two semantics: "semantics of calling" and "semantics of storage". For "semantics of calling": both .class and .il distinguish instance and static methods. For "semantics of storage" CLR stores every method in method table which belongs to specific type, so storage is static. And because storage is static, non-static methods can be called in static way. Not sure if it is same for java. (P.S. static storage is also non-static, because types are represented by type objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not from Java code, no.

If you hand-roll bytecode, then perhaps you could use an `invokestatic` operation to invoke an instance method, but the result of doing so is not defined in the JVM specifications.  Different JVM implementations could -- and probably do -- handle it differently.

Comment: I see, so it is implementation specific.

Comment: To some extent, yes, it is implementation-specific.  But the Java class file format distinguishes between static methods and instance methods -- which is why Java's reflection subsystem can do so -- therefore even if you can trick a JVM into invoking an instance method as if it were static, that doesn't mean it *is* static.